# grunt watch is not replacing sass file.please suggest me what i am doing wrong here

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to watch sass changes but I am not be able to see any changes on main.css whenever I update on sass files.Can some please suggest me what I am doing wrong here I am new to grunt js .

```
 {
        "name": "test-scss",
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "devDependencies": {
            "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
            "grunt": "^1.0.1",
            "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
            "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
            "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
            "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.4.1",
            "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
            "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0",
            "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "build-css": "node-sass --include-path scss sass/style.scss   css/main.css"
        }
    }
    /// here is my gruntjs file configuration

    module.exports = function(grunt) {
        grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            watch: {
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                },
                sass: {
                    files: ['**/*.scss'],
                    task: ['sass']
                },
                html: {
                    files: ['*.html']
                }
            },
            sass: {
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'css/main.css': 'sass/style.scss'
                    }
                }
            },
            connect: {
                sever: {
                    options: {
                        keepalive: true,
                        hostname: 'localhost',
                        port: 3003,
                        base: '.',
                        open: true,
                        watch: true,
                        livereload: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
        grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'watch', 'connect']);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Grunt watch` is a blocking task so `grunt connect` is never reached.

`grunt-contrib-connect` blocks only if  `keepalive: true` is set otherwise it runs as long as grunt is running. As `grunt watch` runs indefinitely you do not need to force `grunt-contrib-connect` to "`keepalive`"

To fix.

```
keepalive: false //turn off keepalive
```

Move `watch` blocking task to execute last

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass','connect','watch']);
```

---

If you absolutely need to run two blocking tasks together you can use a plugin like `grunt-concurrent`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319772/3656963

Or call each task separately using 2 command lines.

Also fix typo: `task: ['sass']` to `tasks: ['sass']`

Comment: I have tried the same but when ever i am making changes in sass file it is not updating the css file and not refreshing browser automatically. i have to do manually grunt -sass and then i have to use grunt to run local server.  please suggest me what i have to do to fix

Comment: Sorry missed one thing. Change  task: ['sass'] to tasks: ['sass']. You are missing the 's'